# Botón submit aceptar todo

Tags: javascript, funciones, botón, submit

tengo un formulario creado con js y necesito crear en la etapa de términos y condiciones un botón de submit que sea "aceptar todo y enviar" y que al pulsarlo se envíe el formulario con todos los Checkbox chequeados.¡Ayuda por favor!

Este es el código de la etapa:

```html
<div class="tab">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 justify-items-center">
            <h3 class="title"><strong>¡Ya tenemos la MEJOR OFERTA para ti! </strong></h3>
            [acceptance Mayordeedad] Declaro que soy mayor de edad[/acceptance]
            [acceptance protecciondedatos optional] Acepto la comunicación de mis datos a terceras partes con
            finalidades publicitarias en los términos expuestos en la Información sobre la <u><a
                    data-target="simpleModal_1" data-toggle="modal">Protección de Datos</a></u> [/acceptance]
            [acceptance aceptacion] Acepto expresamente que mis datos sean tratados para uso comercial (emails,
            teléfono, sms u otros canales) por parte del titular de la web, sus Colaboradores, y/o por terceros. En todo
            caso podré ejercer mis derechos de oposición, acceso, rectificación, cancelación, información, portabilidad,
            limitación de tratamiento y olvido según lo previsto en las condiciones de uso. [/acceptance]
        </div>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 justify-items-center mt">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 justify-items-center min-w">
                [submit id:submit_btn class:button-cf7-pd "Acepto"]
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 justify-items-center min-w">
                <a class="button-cf7-pd wpcf7-form-control" onclick="nextPrev(-1);">No acepto</a>
                <span class="ajax-loader"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Y tu código JS?

Comment: Por favor agrega todo el código relacionado a la pregunta

Comment: Hola, lo he añadido en otra respuesta, gracias!

Comment: No lo pongas como respuesta, pulsa en [edit] y agrégalo en la pregunta misma.

Answer (score 0):

Si es un formulario la solución es fácil:
Crea un botón con una función para el evento click
La función deberá:
poner poner el atributo ckecked a los inputs del formulario
hacer el form submit

Ese es el algoritmo, como no pones tu código JS no es posible ser más concreto. Pero poer un atributo a un objeto del DOM con la propiedad checked del control (objetoInput.checked = true).